# PHP Warning Directive register_global is depriciated in php 5.3

Tags: php, html

I am trying to run selenim test cases and getting error register_globals is depriciated and greater in unknown line 0
Can some help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must on register_globals for do this you can do it on **php.ini** or

```
ini_set('register_globals','1');
```

on php code you can do this by htaccess too like

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value register_globals 1
</IfModule>

<IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
  php_value register_globals 1
</IfModule>

php_flag register_globals 1
```

Comment: if i add these lines in php.in it says parese error in php.ini

Comment: @Swapnil in php.ini you must find **register_globals = off** and make it **on**

Comment: there is no instance of "register_globals=off" in php.in

Comment: search **register_globals** .if you are sure about no any **register_globals** you can add this at last of php.ini **register_globals=on**